# VS Code does not recognise imports because of docker

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, virtualenv

Good day. I was using virtual environment in development stage (for python projects, of course). But one day, I decided to do everything using best practices, and followed one course. In that course, tutor uses docker-compose for all operations, and installs all dependencies to inside docker container. But I'm using vs code, and since no virtual environment is created, vs code does not recognize imports, because it looks at the main interpreter, in which I don't have those dependencies. One way is to install all dependencies to the main interpreter, and I think it is not recommended. Another way, I think, is to create a virtual env for just containing the dependencies for vs code to refer it. But I'm not sure it is best practice or not. What is the best way of developing a python project using docker, and vs code ?

Fun fact: In tutors Vs code, there is no problem :)

Comment: I have a pretty strong opinion that there's nothing wrong with using proven tools like virtual environments for day-to-day development.  Since Docker's major design goal is to isolate containers from their host environment, _by design_ it's hard for a host-based IDE to access tools and libraries that only exist in a container.  VSCode has better support than many others, but in general I default to not including Docker as part of my core development setup.

Comment: (You might consider rewriting this question to ask, for example, how a specific problem you're having with the VSCode+Python+Docker setup could be resolved; "should I use popular tool X or popular tool Y" is likely to be closed as opinion-based.)

Answer (score 0):

morning,here is an example,https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky
you can learn from this project struct.
in a word.you can use virtualenv in your develop env,when you commit your code,you may ingore venv dir,when you deploy your project ,you may use docker-compose to deploy.
feel free

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The first thing to understand is that the interpreter of the virtual environment is isolated from the real environment, so there is no need to call the dependencies in the virtual environment while using the main interpreter.

I think the best way is to unify all operations in the virtual environment, so that the environment will not be disordered.

You can also refer to this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python) for more information about vscode and docker

Answer (score -1):

Morning,
I was having the same issue and the way I fixed it is:

1. install the dependencies on the main computer
2. press `ctrl + shift + p` and select `python: select interpreter`

> Then select the global python environment

Comment: It is important to note that installing dependencies on the main computer and selecting the Python interpreter on the host machine is not considered the recommended approach for resolving the issue. This method can lead to complications, especially when multiple projects have the same package but with different versions.